# how to install emacs24 with gui for suse enterprise server

Tags: linux, emacs, suse

i worked on SUSE enterprise 11, i found it only have emacs22 installed by default, emacs22 can work with its GUI,

i want some feature which has been included in emacs 24, and i try to install it emacs 24 by building source code, but it prompt me that i need to install the gtk2.0 dev for GUI support, i can find the gtk2.0-devel rpm package, but still need to resolve a lot of dependency, this is out of my control, so is there any compiled binarys for emacs24 on my version of operating system, or how can i install it by a easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs 24 will build with the gtk2 X toolkit by default, but you can override that with an argument to the configure command -- this is recommended in any case, because an Emacs built with any version of the Gnome toolkit, and run in daemon mode, will tend to crash when a client disconnects.

Several toolkit bindings are available, but none is required, and given your situation and the need for minimal dependencies, building without a toolkit is the option I recommend. To do so, visit the directory where you unpacked your Emacs source tarball and do

```
./configure --with-x-toolkit=no # ...
make && make install
```

As always, if building to install without root privileges, you'll want to give a `--prefix` argument to configure, specifying some location writable for your account and present in your `$PATH`, so that you can install and run your custom-built Emacs with minimal extra effort.

If you're not accustomed to using X without a toolkit, and frequently make use of the toolbar, menubar, and scrollbar in Emacs, a version built without a toolkit will be rather strange to get used to. On the other hand, if you can't install the necessary dependencies to use a toolkit, then building without one will at least give you a working graphical Emacs. (You don't really need toolbars, menubars, or scrollbars anyway. "Luke, you've switched off your targeting computer. What's wrong?" "Nothing. I'm all right.")